# Use FlaskSQLAlchemy models with SQLAlchemy syntax and vice versa

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm not able to locate a good resource to help me understand how to:

The 1:1 difference, similarities between SQlAlchemy and Flask SQLAlchemy.

I had hit this roadblock earlier as well, the code was kind of scotch taped to work but looking for a long term in-depth solution.

1. Use FlaskSQLAlchemy models with SQLAlchemy syntax .
2. Use SQLAlchemy style declarative_base models -> doing CRUD on them with FlaskSQLAlchemy like syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since Flask-SQLAlchemy is an extension of SQLAlchemy, I think all SQLAlchemy’s method (and syntax’s) Is applicable in your Flask-SQLÀlchemy’s app.
It’s an extension.
You may want to read the documentation https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/